# SQL statement sequential execution for multiple statments

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

If a single SQL file contains 2 SQL statements below each other (as below) for millions of records

Query 1 : `select Id into MyTempTable from TableB b join abc a on a.Id = t.Id`

Query 2 :  `Update TableB set Completed =1`

Is there any chance that query 2 will execute first for some of the records or do we have a guarantee of sequential execution of those statements?

In another words, will Query 2 execution be started only after Query1 finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple queries in a batch then these queries will be executed in the order they appear in the batch.

After the execution of Query 1 is finished then the update query will be executed.
You can run debugger to see the sequential execution.

Answer (score 0):

As answered previously by [Max Vernon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon) [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215601/ms-sql-server-do-multiple-queries-in-a-batch-ever-execute-in-parallel-and-if-so)

> Batch statements are only ever executed serially in the order they
>   appear in the batch.

The only difference with your question is that you seem to not want the update to ever complete if the first statement did not run yet **or** if it failed. 
If you want both to succeed & fail toghether you should wrap them in an explicit transaction.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

select b.Id 
into #MyTempTable 
from TableB b 
join abc a 
on a.Id = b.Id

UPDATE TableB set Completed =1;

COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END 
END CATCH
```